# Hibernate OneToMany Error while adding second Record

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security, h2

I am developing a spring boot application using hibernate and H2 database. After I build an application, the application creates tables as I expected. After tables were created I added a role to the role table manually (`role_id = 1, role = "USER"`) then I run the application. I could add the first user whose role is USER, successfully but when I tried to add the second record I get an error. Also, I add another role (`role_id = 2, role="ADMIN"`) after I could add the first user whose role is ADMIN, successfully. But the second one could not. Why cannot I add records more than one?

The Error is

> *could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [\"UK_IT77EQ964JHFQTU54081EBTIO_INDEX_B ON PUBLIC.USER_ROLE(ROLE_ID)
>   VALUES (2, 1)\"; SQL statement:\ninsert into user_role (user_id,
>   role_id) values (?, ?) [23505-197]]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement.

Here are my code blocks.

The `User.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int roleId;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Register Method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user){
    if(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Username already exist");
    }   

    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    roles.add(roleRepository.findByRole("USER"));
    user.setRoles(roles);

    return new ResponseEntity<User>(userRepository.save(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Database Tables

```
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.USER_ROLE( 
USER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
ROLE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL 
);


CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.USER( 
    USER_ID INTEGER DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR 
PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_2149846F_F3B8_4E83_9B93_C1C67BF9DEA9) NOT NULL 
NULL_TO_DEFAULT SEQUENCE 
PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_2149846F_F3B8_4E83_9B93_C1C67BF9DEA9, 
    NAME VARCHAR(255), 
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(255), 
    USERNAME VARCHAR(255) 
);

CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.ROLE( 
    ROLE_ID INTEGER DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR 
PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_44142DBD_5E4A_4D30_AB39_36956E6C6DAF) NOT NULL 
NULL_TO_DEFAULT SEQUENCE 
PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_44142DBD_5E4A_4D30_AB39_36956E6C6DAF, 
    ROLE VARCHAR(255) 
);
```

Comment: Can you please post the repository for the `user_role` table as well? And yes, please check if there is any constraint associated with that table. Kudos!

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have not repository for user_role table. I have an joinTable annotation for this table in User class.

Comment: You have a `user_role` table right?

Comment: Yes I have an user_role table. As I mentioned in question. When I post first user to the user table, user_role table is filled automatically (eq. user_id = 1, role_id = 1).